# How to Set a Different List and View Template for a Magento Category?

Tags: templates, magento

Let's say I have two categories.

I want first category to use template/catalog/list_a.phtml, but I want second category use template/catalog/list_b.phtml for their product listing template. I also like first category to use template/catalog/view_a.phtml and second category to use template/catalog/view_b.phtml.

I found a solution to use a different layout for each category. Here is the solution [How to display category custom design layout in product view page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667676/how-to-display-category-custom-design-layout-in-product-view-page)

so..in order to use different listing and view template, I ended up with the following code.

```
<CATEGORY_9>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/cashandcarry.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/> 
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>

</CATEGORY_9>
```

The problem is that my product listing template displays the default template as well. I mean, both default and my custom listing template are displayed.

How do I display my custom listing template only?